# CSS Nesting Problem - Reading container information

Tags: css, nested

This problem comes up from time to time when I work with CSS, here is the issue I face.

My current code is:

```
<div class="entry">
  <div>
    <blockquote><p>quoted text</p></blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my css, I have:

```
.entry p {margin: 10px}
blockquote {stuff}
blockquote p {margin: 0px}
```

I would think the paragraph inside the blockquote would read from 'blockquote p', but instead it takes the margin: 10px from '.entry p'.

Why does it read from 'entry p' instead of 'blockquote p'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While usually in CSS the last declaration wins, that is only true if [they both share the same specificity weight](http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/). However, if the 2 selectors are not of equal specificity, the lower one will be overridden *even if it comes later in the code*.

Since a *classname* selector has a higher specificity value than a *tagname* selector, your second declaration is being overridden.

To give the later one a higher specificity, you'll have to further qualify it:

```
.entry blockquote p {margin: 0px}
```

Or use the dreaded [`!important`](http://css-tricks.com/9462-when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/):

```
blockquote p { margin: 0px !important }
```

Use the second method only when the first one fails (In your example, the first one will do just fine).

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

That is to say `.entry p` is higher than `blockquote p`

Changing it to the following would solve it (although there are other solutions)

```
.entry blockquote p
```

Comment: I was thinking of .entry div blockquote p {} which would of been a bit overkill.

Comment: Maybe, but it would also work. As I pointed out *there are other solutions.*

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying a class for .entry, which is specific - not global.

Have you tried:

```
.entry blockquote p
{
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of document order for CSS, but rather of selector specificity.  See [Calculating a selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

When we declare a class, it would get the first preference over the CSS defined for tags.